# React with Socket IO: Broadcast is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets

I am doing a game using Socket IO. Each room is using a channel of communication. When the player make a bet, I want to send to the oponnent. However, the player is receving the message too

This is my React component

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react"
import { useParams, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

import { BACKEND_URL } from  '../../constants'

export default function Room() {
    const { id } = useParams(); 

    const [room, setRoom] = useState({});
    const [game,setGame] = useState({
        state: 'waiting',
        payload: {},
    })

    const [price, setPrice] = useState(10);

    /**
     * This function verify if the room exist
     * If exists, set a variable with its properties
     * If doesn't exist, return to the initial page
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/rooms`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(rooms => {
                let auxRoom = undefined;
                rooms.map((room) => {
                    if(room.id == id) {
                        auxRoom = room;
                    }
                })
                setRoom(auxRoom)
            })
    }, []);

    /**
     * This function set the begin of the game
     * Define that the player is waiting 
     * And wait the signal to begin the game
     */
    useEffect(() => {
        const socket = socketIOClient(BACKEND_URL);
        socket.emit("waiting room", id);
        socket.on("start room", () => {
            setGame({
                state: 'playing',
                payload: {}
            })

            socket.on('opponent made bet', (price) => {
                console.log("opponent")
                console.log(price)
            })

        })
    }, [])

    function toBet(event) {
        const socket = socketIOClient(BACKEND_URL);
        event.preventDefault();
        //Emiting that the player made a bet
        socket.emit("make a bet", id, price);
    }

    return(
        <div>
            { !room ? //If the room doesn't exist, should be redirect
                <Redirect to="/"/>
                : null }

            Estamos na sala {id}!

            {
                game.state == 'playing' ?
                <div className="game">
                    <div className="scoreboard">
                    </div>
                    <div className="arena">
                        <label>Escolha o preço do petróleo:</label>
                        <select value={price} onChange={(event) => setPrice(event.target.value)}>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option value="20">20</option>
                            <option value="30">30</option>
                        </select>
                        <button onClick={toBet}>Apostar</button>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                : null
            }

        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my backend

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

let rooms = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Room 1',
        owner: 'Bruna',
        amountOfPlayers: 0,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Room 2',
        owner: 'Amancio',
        amountOfPlayers: 0,
    }
]

function indexRoom(id) {
    for(let i = 0; i < rooms.length; i++)
        if(rooms[i].id == id)
            return i;
}

app.get('/rooms', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.json(rooms)
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    /**
     * Socket that is responsible for start the game
     * When two players connect, the game begins
     */
    socket.on('waiting room', id => {
        //A player get in the room
        socket.join(id); 
        let index = indexRoom(id);

        if(index != undefined) {
            rooms[index].amountOfPlayers++;
            //When are two players, should start the game
            if(rooms[index].amountOfPlayers >= 2) {
                io.to(id).emit('start room');
            }
        }
    })

    socket.on('make a bet', (id, price) => {
        socket.broadcast.to(id).emit('opponent made bet', price)
    })

})

http.listen(8080, () => {
})
```

When a player make a bet, it should emit a 'make a bet' and only the opponent receive the price of the bet. But this is not how it's working.
This is the console of the two players after I click in the button one time: In the console of the player I click in the button, it's printed twice!!! I don't want to print, only in the opponent (that is printed once)

[image: After a bet]

I'm very beginner in the Socket.io, sorry if it's a basic concept.

Comment: if you click the button 3 times, does the console log the output three times?

Comment: yes @Ayudh. The console the page I clicked it printed "opponent 10 \n opponent 10 \n opponent 10 \n opponent 10 \n opponent 10 \n opponent 10" and in the opponent "opponent 10 \n opponent 10 \n opponent 10"

Answer (score 0):

remove `const socket = ...` from your `toBet` function

Comment: is it the same output? Please have a look at the updated answer. Do the same for your toBet function. only declare socket once

Comment: I have two browser open. In the first browser A, I click the button and it is printed "opponent" twice. In the second browser B, it's printed "oponnent" one time. If i click in the button of the browser B, the browser B printed "oponnent" one time and the browser A printed "oponnent" two times.

Comment: I think the problem is in the start.on("opponent made bet") inside the start.on("start room"). But I don't know how to fix